# Do something depend on Time-based

Tags: processing

```java
switch(mode) {
    case 0:
      if (millis() - timer >= 100) {
        file.play();
        timer = millis();
      }

      break;
    case 1:
      if (millis() - timer >= 1000) {
        file1.play();
        timer = millis();
      }
      break;
  }
```

I want create a time-based program like a traffic light.
It will play the sound and last 3 seconds. After 3 second, it will turn into another sound and last 10 seconds.After 10 second, it will turn into first sound. And so on.  How can i count the time for two case?

Answer (score 0):

The conditions you use to compare `millis()` and `timer` look of in terms of logic. You might want to change the values to be 3 and 10 seconds (instead of 0.1 and 1 seconds)

It feels like you simply need 3 states:

- > It will play the sound and last 3 seconds.
- > After 3 second, it will turn into another sound and last 10 seconds
- > After 10 second, it will turn into first sound.

Something like this:

```
int mode;

int timer;

void setup() {
  println("starting in 1st mode, seconds:",second());
}
void draw() {


  switch(mode) {
  case 0:
    if (millis() - timer >= 3000) {
      println("play sound 1, seconds:",second());
      timer = millis();
      mode = 1;//change to the state to the next one
    }

    break;
  case 1:
    if (millis() - timer >= 3000) {
      print("play sound 2, seconds:",second());
      timer = millis();
      mode = 2;//go to next mode
    }
    break;
  case 2:
    if (millis() - timer >= 10000) {//wait 10s
      println("\n10s passed, going to 1st mode, seconds:",second());
      timer = millis();
      mode = 0;//go to next mode, after 10s
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

In terms of timing, you should have states looping in 3s, 3s and 10s increments.

I'm not 100% if sound will play as expected, but test with some `println()` commands first to see if what state happens at what time you expect it to, then simply trigger the sound you need in it's right place.

demo time:

```js
var mode = 0;

var timer;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(100,100);
  timer = millis()
  console.log("starting in 1st mode, seconds:",second());
}
function draw() {
  background(255);
  text("mode: " + mode + "\nseconds: " + second(),10,10);

  switch(mode) {
  case 0:
    if (millis() - timer >= 3000) {
      console.log("play sound 1, seconds:",second());
      timer = millis();
      mode = 1;//change to the state to the next one
    }

    break;
  case 1:
    if (millis() - timer >= 3000) {
      console.log("play sound 2, seconds:",second());
      timer = millis();
      mode = 2;//go to next mode
    }
    break;
  case 2:
    if (millis() - timer >= 10000) {//wait 10s
      console.log("10s passed, going to 1st mode, seconds:",second());
      timer = millis();
      mode = 0;//go to next mode, after 10s
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.5/p5.min.js"></script>
```